# lunching a caliper in fabric test

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

hope someone can help ,i wanted to run a caliper on fabric auction-simple ,but after binding with `bash npx caliper bind --caliper-bind-sut fabric:2.2, the in test-net folder :`bash
./network.sh up createChannel -s couchdb

###### To deploy the Go version

````bash
./network.sh deployCC -ccn fabcar -ccp ../../caliper-benchmarks/src/fabric/samples/fabcar/go -ccl go 
in `caliper-benchmarks` directory

```bash
npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-networkconfig networks/fabric/test-network.yaml --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/samples/fabric/fa
bcar/config.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled
i tried to remove the node-module folder and package-lock.json and run npm install to have the dependencies needed still have the same problem
````